# Unable to install QGIS 2.2 successfully?

Tags: qgis, installation, download

I'm having problem in installing QGIS 2.2. (64 Bit).

After downloading & installing, when I click the OSGeo4WShell, I get a message:

> C:\***.exe not a valid win32 application

and ends with:

> Access denied

What should I do?

Comment: Could you add the exact error message?

Comment: C:\PROGRA~1\QGISVA~1\bin\gdalinfo.exe is not a valid Win32 application. (Even while installing, this kind of error message keep on coming and after clicking "OK" for each message it got installed.)

Comment: Are you sure you are running a 64bit Windows? Maybe you get lucky with the 32bit version. Did you install as administrator? Could be that the Visual C Runtime were not installed. Take a look at the postinstall.log file in C:\Programs\QGIS Valmiera.

Answer (score 3):

The standalone version of QGIS on Windows sometimes stumbles over folder names with blanks. Unfortunately, that is the default place where Windows places the programmes into `C:\Program files\...`.

So you can use either:

- an installation path without blanks, like `C:\QGISValmiera\`
- use the OSGEO4W setup.exe, which installs to `C:\OSGEO4W\` or `C:\OSGEO4W64\`